# How do I publish a django web app to Google App Engine from Visual Studio 2012

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine

I am trying to set up a django application in Visual Studio 2012 that will publish to Google App Engine.  I have a simple hello World Application set up in Visual Studio using pytools that  I can run successfully in the development environment.

I added an app.yaml file, downloaded the AppEngine SDK and imported the existing application to the Google App Engine Launcher application.  If I start the application locally using the App Engine Launcher, it starts but the page is just an error.  I get the following from the log:

```
2013-05-23 07:47:03 Running command: "['C:\\Python27\\pythonw.exe', 'C:\\Program Files\\Google\\google_appengine\\dev_appserver.py', '--skip_sdk_update_check=yes', '--port=8080', '--admin_port=8000', 'Z:\\gridtreecontrol\\GridTreeView\\GridTreeView']"
INFO     2013-05-23 07:47:09,496 devappserver2.py:522] Skipping SDK update check.
WARNING  2013-05-23 07:47:09,523 api_server.py:329] Could not initialize images API; you are likely missing the Python "PIL" module.
INFO     2013-05-23 07:47:09,543 api_server.py:153] Starting API server at: http://localhost:61149
INFO     2013-05-23 07:47:09,552 dispatcher.py:164] Starting server "default" running at: http://localhost:8080
INFO     2013-05-23 07:47:09,558 admin_server.py:117] Starting admin server at:     http://localhost:8000
ERROR    2013-05-23 12:47:32,108 wsgi.py:235] 
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\runtime\wsgi.py", line 223, in Handle
result = handler(dict(self._environ), self._StartResponse)
File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\lib\django-1.4\django\core\handlers\wsgi.py", line 219, in __call__
self.load_middleware()
File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\lib\django-1.4\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 39, in load_middleware
for middleware_path in settings.MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES:
File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\lib\django-1.4\django\utils\functional.py", line 184, in inner
self._setup()
File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\lib\django-1.4\django\conf\__init__.py", line 42, in _setup
self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\lib\django-1.4\django\conf\__init__.py", line 95, in __init__
raise ImportError("Could not import settings '%s' (Is it on sys.path?): %s" % (self.SETTINGS_MODULE, e))
ImportError: Could not import settings 'settings' (Is it on sys.path?): No module named settings
INFO     2013-05-23 07:47:32,128 server.py:585] default: "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 -
```

It seems like it wants me to make some adjustments to sys.path, but I feel like if I did that, it won't propagate those changes to the production server on Google App Engine.  I have tried publishing the application to the server, but get the same error there.

I do not get this error when running the application in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not try to develop a standalone Django application and then try to convert it to GAE. There are many differences in running Django inside GAE, and it's best to start from there in the first place.

I don't know why it's important to you to be able to run your app "inside" VS. Again, you should use the GAE development server - you can continue to write your code in VS, and the devserver will even reload when it detects code changes. You might be able to configure VS to use the GAE devserver instead of the Django one, but it sounds like a lot of unnecessary fiddling.

Comment: Thank you.  That was very helpful.  Based on your answer, I found a video on installing and running djangoappengine at:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-PcrSD1AwwQ

And found the nonrel appengine branch of django here:

http://www.allbuttonspressed.com/projects/djangoappengine#installation